# $I_n=\int_0^1{x^ne^x\,dx}$. Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}nI_n$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

$$I_n=\int_0^1{x^ne^x\,dx}$$ 
Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}nI_n$
Here is what I tried and I don't understand what I did wrong, because I checked the result and it is not right.

First I calculated $\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n$ using the Squeeze Theorem and it is equal to $0$. Then the above limit evaluates to $\infty * 0$, which means it can be rewritten as $\frac{0}{0}$ to then apply L'hospital. Then:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^1{x^ne^x\,dx}}{\frac{1}{n}} $$
Now, here might be where I am wrong, but I think that $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(t)dt=f(x)$. Then after aplying L'hospital the limit becomes: 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{e}{\frac{1}{n^2}}=-\infty$$
The limit should be equal to $e$, what did I do wrong?

Comment: In your case it is not the upper limit of integration that depends on $n$ but rather the integrand.

Comment: Here is a remark. It can be shown that $I_0=e-1$ and $$I_n=e-nI_{n-1}$$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$.  Therefore, $$I_n=(-1)^n\big((!n)e-(n!)\big),$$ where $(!n)$ is the $n$th derangement (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: @WETutorialSchool: your recursion itself gives the desired limit as $e$ because $I_n\to 0$. There is no need to explicitly evaluate $I_n$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  I already know that (Gary's solution is basically the same as what you just said).  But that wasn't the intention of my remark.  I just thought it was interesting to know the value of $I_n$ exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration by parts shows that
$$
n\int_0^1 {x^n e^x dx}  = \frac{n}{{n + 1}}e - \frac{n}{{n + 1}}\int_0^1 {x^{n + 1} e^x dx} .
$$
Hence
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } n\int_0^1 {x^n e^x dx}  = e - \int_0^1 {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } x^{n + 1} e^x dx}  = e,
$$
since the integrand tends to $0$ pointwise for $0<x<1$. The change in the order of integration and the limit is permitted since the integrand is at most $e^x$ which is intgerable on $(0,1)$.